# Class not recognized in different thread due to classloading

Tags: java, class, bytecode

I have ran into a problem concerning classloaders in Java.

For some reason I have encrypted a class with AES, when my program starts it decrypts the class using a key provided by a web service. I have written my own classloader which calls `super.defineClass(String, byte[], int, int)` which works 100%

But when I create a thread (lets say swing) and use the class I decrypted previously it throws an exception where the magic number is wrong which is understandable (compilation version messed up due to classloading). However the class works perfectly fine when I do not use it in a thread which is not an option.

How would I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried the solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822004/change-classloader

Maybe it can help you.

Comment: It has nothing to do with threads.  If you load the same class with two different class loaders you have, in essence, two different classes.

Comment: Are you getting the key in a seperate thread properly? Have you tried to dump the decrypted bytes to verify they are the same? If the magic number at the beginning of the classfile is wrong, that means it's probably garbage data.

Comment: Without seeing actual code, that’s guessworking.